# magento manage category url navigates to homepage

Tags: php, magento

Very first time using magento and trying to learn it by myself. I have installed it on my server and trying to add categories for products.

On clicking manage category from admin panel, it redirects me to website homepage.

After checking logs I came to know that it throwing this warning:

```
text/x-log system.log ( ASCII text, with very long lines )

2016-05-20T05:04:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:include(Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Mgvp/Catalog/Category/Helper/Sortby/Available.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/<hostname>/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-05-20T05:04:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Mgvp/Catalog/Category/Helper/Sortby/Available.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/<hostname>/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-05-20T05:04:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Mgvp/Catalog/Category/Helper/Sortby/Available.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/<hostname>/public_html/app/code/local:/home/<hostname>/public_html/app/code/community:/home/<hostname>/public_html/app/code/core:/home/<hostname>/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/<hostname>/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

**Tried so far:**

1. I have tried to search some similar questions in stack overflow. I have
   tried one solution i.e. to grant all permissions if file is exist. I
   have granted all permissions to `Autoload.php`
2. I have tried to replace the app folder which does not work.

Its not working. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

some core files are missing. Please replace the app folder the magento directory. thanks